# How to unmarshall when you have xml namespace?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, xml-namespaces

I am trying to unmarshall an xml using a namespace to create an object from it.  I am getting exceptions that the element is not expected.  Here is what I've got.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="package")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class DenPackage { 
.....

}
```

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://www.leap.com/rest/package">
</pkg:package>
```

The exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.leap.com/rest/package", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{}package>
```

Should the `@XmlRootElement(name="package")` be the thing that changes?  Or if you know more than I do, any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Case #1 - All Elements Are Namespace Qualified

If all (or most) of the elements in your document are going to be qualified with the same namespace use the `@XmlSchema` annotation to specify the namespace qualification.  `@XmlSchema` is a package level annotation so it goes on a special class called `package-info` that looks something like.  The combination of specifying a `namespace` and `elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` means that this namespace will be applied to all elements that haven't overridden the namespace.

**package-info.java**

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.leap.com/rest/package",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.leap.rest.pkg;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

### Use Case #2 - Just the Root Element Is Namespace Qualified

If just the root element is namespace qualified then use the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="package", namespace = "http://www.leap.com/rest/package")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class DenPackage { 
.....

}
```

### For More Information

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Wow, this is exact-o-mundo.  Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the namespace attribute:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="package", namespace = "http://www.leap.com/rest/package")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `pkg namespace` on your class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="package" namespace = "http://www.leap.com/rest/package")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class DenPackage { 
.....

}
```

Remember, if you have child elements in your xml (not shown in your sample) and they also belong to namespace, then define namespace for them as well as  *namespace is not "inherited" by the fields on the bound class*